# Login with scrapy doesn't work

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have recently started using [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) and was setting it up for a typical task of scraping a webpage which requires authentication.

My idea is to start with the login page, submit the form and then download the data from other login protected pages.

I can see that I am authenticated, however, I see that I am stuck in a loop of redirects when it goes to the download page.

My spider class looks like below:

```
class MySpiderWithLogin(Spider):
    name = 'my-spider'

    download_url = 'https://example.com/files/1.zip'

    login_url = 'https://example.com/login'

    login_user = '...'
    login_password = '...'

    def start_requests(self):
        # let's start by sending a first request to login page
        yield Request(self.login_url, self.parse_login)

    def parse_login(self, response):
        # got the login page, let's fill the login form...
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                           formdata={'username': self.login_user, 'password': self.login_password},
                           callback=self.start_crawl,
                           dont_filter = True)


    def start_crawl(self, response):
        # OK, we're in, let's start crawling the protected pages
        yield Request(self.download_url, dont_filter = True)

    def parse(self, response):
        # do stuff with the logged in respons
        inspect_response(response, self)
        return
```

What I see after running the spider is a redirect loop as below. I have abstracted `login_page`, `download_page` and some query parameters along with them namely ticket, jsession_id, cas_check

```
2016-12-21 18:06:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET <login_page>>
2016-12-21 18:06:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET <login_page>>
2016-12-21 18:06:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET <login_page/j_spring_cas_security_check;jsessionid=bar?ticket=foo> from <POST <login_page/j_spring_cas_security_check;jsessionid=bar?ticket=foo>
2016-12-21 18:06:42 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET home_page>
2016-12-21 18:06:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET <home page>>
2016-12-21 18:06:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET login_page>>from <GET download_page>
2016-12-21 18:06:47 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to < download_page?ticket=biz> from <GET login_page>
2016-12-21 18:06:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET download_page> from <GET download_page?ticket=biz>
2016-12-21 18:06:54 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET login_page>>from <GET download_page>
....
....
2016-12-21 18:07:34 [scrapy] DEBUG: Discarding <GET download_page?ticket=biz_100>: max redirections reached
```

I have set my User-agent to that of a browser in settings.py but to no effect here. Any ideas what could possibly be wrong?

Here's payload of login form from a successful request from a browser for reference:

```
url: login_page/jsessionid=...?service=../j_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D...
method: POST
payload:
    - username: ...
    - password: ...
    - lt: e1s1
    - _eventId: submit
    - submit: Sign In
```

**UPDATE**

Using python's requests library works like a charm for the same url. Also it would be worthy to mention that the website uses [Jasig CAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home) for authentication, which makes the download url one-time accessible for a given ticket. For any further access, a new ticket needs to be issued.

I am guessing that might be the reason why Scrapy's Request is stuck in redirects as it might not be built around the one-time access scenario.

Comment: Please provide the site URL so I can investigate further.

Comment: I think I'll need the username and password my friend

Comment: I'd need them for testing purposes. If there's any way you could change it later, please provide them and do so when I'm done. Else, I won't be able to help you, sorry.